# Scala interop with Java questionmark generics

Tags: scala, generics, scala-java-interop

**EDIT** I have made the example self-contained.

Suppose in java I have

src/main/java/FooFactory.java

```
interface FooFactory {
  Foo<?> create();
  <T> void enhance(Foo<T> foo, FooEnhancer<? super T> enhancer);
}
```

and src/main/java/Foo.java

```
interface Foo<T> {}
```

and src/main/java/FooEnhancer.java

```
interface FooEnhancer<T> {}
```

(and you can't change these interfaces because they belong to someone else.)

Then in scala you have

```
object DummyFooEnhancer extends FooEnhancer[Any]


trait FooHdlr {
  def fooFactory: FooFactory

  val foo = fooFactory.create
  fooFactory.enhance(foo, DummyFooEnhancer)

}
```

This doesn't compile because FooEnhancer and Foo are invariant but `foo` is a `Foo<?>` whereas `DummyFooEnhancer` is a `Foo[Any]`. Changing `Any` to `AnyRef` doesn't work for the same reason.

Then I reasoned that, well, ? is a *specific* type that is certainly not known at compile time and that may not necessarily be `AnyRef`/`Object`, so what if I do this?

```
case class DummyFooEnhancer[T] extends FooEnhancer[T]


trait FooHdlr {
  def fooFactory: FooFactory

  val foo = fooFactory.create
  fooFactory.enhance(foo, new DummyFooEnhancer)

}
```

But this causes scalac to stackoverflow! It's looping with

```
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeVar.isGround(Types.scala:3082)
```

calling itself.

Interestingly if I replace `? super T` with `T` it works fine, but in real life I can't do this because it's in code I don't control

Comment: @райтфолд AnyRef has the exact same problem as Any, because ListenableScheduledFuture is invariant and it's a ListenableScheduledFuture<?> not a ListenableScheduledFuture<Object>.

Comment: I find you question very hard to follow. Is [this](https://gist.github.com/rightfold/d53f6ec72bb0c62ac109) an accurate equivalent?

Comment: @райтфолд edited. is it clearer now?